# How to clear glide cache only when changing firebase-storage picture?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I want to know how to clear the glide cache with something similar to this:

```
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) 
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
```

But only when the user changes his profilepicture (the target) that he has saved under images/$userid

Right now, the picture just gets taken from the cache and isn't up to date with the picture on the server, but for performance reasons I cant reload the picture everytime.

What would the best practise be in my case?